# Do Intel 9th gen mobile i9 CPUs use soldered IHS instead of thermal paste?

Tags: cpu

I only found information that the more powerful 9th gen **desktop CPUs** have their integrated heat spredders soldered on:

https://www.techpowerup.com/246847/intel-confirms-soldered-ihs-for-9th-gen-core-series

https://venturebeat.com/2018/10/08/intel-solder-9900k-i9/

https://www.eteknix.com/intel-soldered-ihs-9th-gen-core-cpus/

but I couldn't find any information about the new 9th gen mobile CPUs (i9 9880H for example). Is there any information about what kind of thermal solution they use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently mobile cpus don’t use an IHS, that's why the information could not be found. They are all direct die cooling and the thermal paste is the choice of the laptop manufacturer.